# Python/Scipy Kolmogorov-Zurbenko filter?

Tags: python, scipy, filtering

I'm looking for a Python-based Kolmogorov-Zurbenko filter which receives a time-series input and filters it based on a window size and number of iterations and haven't found anything that seems to work. Has anyone had better luck than I?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have just been looking into the same issue. The actual KZ filter is very easy in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
def kz(series, window, iterations):
    """KZ filter implementation
    series is a pandas series
    window is the filter window m in the units of the data (m = 2q+1)
    iterations is the number of times the moving average is evaluated
    """
    z = series.copy()
    for i in range(iterations):
        z = pd.rolling_mean(z, window=window, min_periods=1, center=True)
    return z
```

What cannot be easily realized to my knowledge is the adaptive version of the Kologorov Zurbenko filter (KZA). This would at least require a rolling_mean method which allows for the specification of different window lengths to the left and right of the center. The C code at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kza/index.html looks fairly simple and straightforward, but it requires loops and would therefore be quite slow if implemented in Python directly.

Comment: A complete implementation became available in 2017 on GitHub: 
https://github.com/Kismuz/kolmogorov-zurbenko-filter/blob/69c4ec2059621e19b6e4584a7c3e2d11b83fe8e2/kolzur_filter.py